# Creating trackbars to scroll large image and upper and lower boundaries (Pyhton / OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar

I am trying to create scrollbars in a window created by OpenCv python. Specifically, I want merge this HSV scroll bar code in the answer (1) ([Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv)) with this zoom in zoom out scroll bar code in the answer (2) ([Creating trackbars to scroll large image in OpenCV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595958/creating-trackbars-to-scroll-large-image-in-opencv-python)). Both working separately, but I would like to use them in the same window.

code (1) ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv)

```
def nothing(x):
    pass

# Load image
image = cv2.imread("XXX.jpg")

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# Resize a window

cv2.resizeWindow('image', 1,1)

# Create trackbars for color change
# Hue is from 0-179 for Opencv
cv2.createTrackbar('HMin', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('HMax', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)

# Set default value for Max HSV trackbars
cv2.setTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image', 179)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image', 255)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image', 255)

# Initialize HSV min/max values
hMin = sMin = vMin = hMax = sMax = vMax = 0
phMin = psMin = pvMin = phMax = psMax = pvMax = 0


while(1):
    # Get current positions of all trackbars
    hMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMin', 'image')
    sMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMin', 'image')
    vMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMin', 'image')
    hMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image')
    sMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image')
    vMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image')

    # Set minimum and maximum HSV values to display
    lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
    upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])

    # Convert to HSV format and color threshold
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    # Print if there is a change in HSV value
    if((phMin != hMin) | (psMin != sMin) | (pvMin != vMin) | (phMax != hMax) | (psMax != sMax) | (pvMax != vMax) ):
        print("(hMin = %d , sMin = %d, vMin = %d), (hMax = %d , sMax = %d, vMax = %d)" % (hMin , sMin , vMin, hMax, sMax , vMax))
        phMin = hMin
        psMin = sMin
        pvMin = vMin
        phMax = hMax
        psMax = sMax
        pvMax = vMax

    # Display result image
    cv2.imshow('image', result)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Code (2) [Creating trackbars to scroll large image in OpenCV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595958/creating-trackbars-to-scroll-large-image-in-opencv-python)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np

class PanZoomWindow(object):
    """ Controls an OpenCV window. Registers a mouse listener so that:
        1. right-dragging up/down zooms in/out
        2. right-clicking re-centers
        3. trackbars scroll vertically and horizontally 
    You can open multiple windows at once if you specify different window names.
    You can pass in an onLeftClickFunction, and when the user left-clicks, this 
    will call onLeftClickFunction(y,x), with y,x in original image coordinates."""
    def __init__(self, img, windowName = 'PanZoomWindow', onLeftClickFunction = None):
        self.WINDOW_NAME = windowName
        self.H_TRACKBAR_NAME = 'x'
        self.V_TRACKBAR_NAME = 'y'
        self.img = img
        self.onLeftClickFunction = onLeftClickFunction
        self.TRACKBAR_TICKS = 1000
        self.panAndZoomState = PanAndZoomState(img.shape, self)
        self.lButtonDownLoc = None
        self.mButtonDownLoc = None
        self.rButtonDownLoc = None
        cv2.namedWindow(self.WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        self.redrawImage()
        cv2.setMouseCallback(self.WINDOW_NAME, self.onMouse)
        cv2.createTrackbar(self.H_TRACKBAR_NAME, self.WINDOW_NAME, 0, self.TRACKBAR_TICKS, self.onHTrackbarMove)
        cv2.createTrackbar(self.V_TRACKBAR_NAME, self.WINDOW_NAME, 0, self.TRACKBAR_TICKS, self.onVTrackbarMove)
    def onMouse(self,event, x,y,_ignore1,_ignore2):
        """ Responds to mouse events within the window. 
        The x and y are pixel coordinates in the image currently being displayed.
        If the user has zoomed in, the image being displayed is a sub-region, so you'll need to
        add self.panAndZoomState.ul to get the coordinates in the full image."""
        if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            return
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
            #record where the user started to right-drag
            self.mButtonDownLoc = np.array([y,x])
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONUP and self.mButtonDownLoc is not None:
            #the user just finished right-dragging
            dy = y - self.mButtonDownLoc[0]
            pixelsPerDoubling = 0.2*self.panAndZoomState.shape[0] #lower = zoom more
            changeFactor = (1.0+abs(dy)/pixelsPerDoubling)
            changeFactor = min(max(1.0,changeFactor),5.0)
            if changeFactor < 1.05:
                dy = 0 #this was a click, not a draw. So don't zoom, just re-center.
            if dy > 0: #moved down, so zoom out.
                zoomInFactor = 1.0/changeFactor
            else:
                zoomInFactor = changeFactor
#            print("zoomFactor: %s"%zoomFactor)
            self.panAndZoomState.zoom(self.mButtonDownLoc[0], self.mButtonDownLoc[1], zoomInFactor)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            #the user pressed the left button. 
            coordsInDisplayedImage = np.array([y,x])
            if np.any(coordsInDisplayedImage < 0) or np.any(coordsInDisplayedImage > self.panAndZoomState.shape[:2]):
                print("you clicked outside the image area")
            else:
                print("you clicked on %s within the zoomed rectangle"%coordsInDisplayedImage)
                coordsInFullImage = self.panAndZoomState.ul + coordsInDisplayedImage
                print("this is %s in the actual image"%coordsInFullImage)
                print("this pixel holds %s, %s"%(self.img[coordsInFullImage[0],coordsInFullImage[1]]))
                if self.onLeftClickFunction is not None:
                    self.onLeftClickFunction(coordsInFullImage[0],coordsInFullImage[1])
        #you can handle other mouse click events here
    def onVTrackbarMove(self,tickPosition):
        self.panAndZoomState.setYFractionOffset(float(tickPosition)/self.TRACKBAR_TICKS)
    def onHTrackbarMove(self,tickPosition):
        self.panAndZoomState.setXFractionOffset(float(tickPosition)/self.TRACKBAR_TICKS)
    def redrawImage(self):
        pzs = self.panAndZoomState
        cv2.imshow(self.WINDOW_NAME, self.img[pzs.ul[0]:pzs.ul[0]+pzs.shape[0], pzs.ul[1]:pzs.ul[1]+pzs.shape[1]])

class PanAndZoomState(object):
    """ Tracks the currently-shown rectangle of the image.
    Does the math to adjust this rectangle to pan and zoom."""
    MIN_SHAPE = np.array([50,50])
    def __init__(self, imShape, parentWindow):
        self.ul = np.array([0,0]) #upper left of the zoomed rectangle (expressed as y,x)
        self.imShape = np.array(imShape[0:2])
        self.shape = self.imShape #current dimensions of rectangle
        self.parentWindow = parentWindow
    def zoom(self,relativeCy,relativeCx,zoomInFactor):
        self.shape = (self.shape.astype(np.float)/zoomInFactor).astype(np.int)
        #expands the view to a square shape if possible. (I don't know how to get the actual window aspect ratio)
        self.shape[:] = np.max(self.shape) 
        self.shape = np.maximum(PanAndZoomState.MIN_SHAPE,self.shape) #prevent zooming in too far
        c = self.ul+np.array([relativeCy,relativeCx])
        self.ul = (c-self.shape/2).astype(np.int)
        self._fixBoundsAndDraw()
    def _fixBoundsAndDraw(self):
        """ Ensures we didn't scroll/zoom outside the image. 
        Then draws the currently-shown rectangle of the image."""
#        print("in self.ul: %s shape: %s"%(self.ul,self.shape))
        self.ul = np.maximum(0,np.minimum(self.ul, self.imShape-self.shape))
        self.shape = np.minimum(np.maximum(PanAndZoomState.MIN_SHAPE,self.shape), self.imShape-self.ul)
#        print("out self.ul: %s shape: %s"%(self.ul,self.shape))
        yFraction = float(self.ul[0])/max(1,self.imShape[0]-self.shape[0])
        xFraction = float(self.ul[1])/max(1,self.imShape[1]-self.shape[1])
        cv2.setTrackbarPos(self.parentWindow.H_TRACKBAR_NAME, self.parentWindow.WINDOW_NAME,int(xFraction*self.parentWindow.TRACKBAR_TICKS))
        cv2.setTrackbarPos(self.parentWindow.V_TRACKBAR_NAME, self.parentWindow.WINDOW_NAME,int(yFraction*self.parentWindow.TRACKBAR_TICKS))
        self.parentWindow.redrawImage()
    def setYAbsoluteOffset(self,yPixel):
        self.ul[0] = min(max(0,yPixel), self.imShape[0]-self.shape[0])
        self._fixBoundsAndDraw()
    def setXAbsoluteOffset(self,xPixel):
        self.ul[1] = min(max(0,xPixel), self.imShape[1]-self.shape[1])
        self._fixBoundsAndDraw()
    def setYFractionOffset(self,fraction):
        """ pans so the upper-left zoomed rectange is "fraction" of the way down the image."""
        self.ul[0] = int(round((self.imShape[0]-self.shape[0])*fraction))
        self._fixBoundsAndDraw()
    def setXFractionOffset(self,fraction):
        """ pans so the upper-left zoomed rectange is "fraction" of the way right on the image."""
        self.ul[1] = int(round((self.imShape[1]-self.shape[1])*fraction))
        self._fixBoundsAndDraw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    infile = "XXX.jpg"
    myImage = cv2.imread(infile,cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
    window = PanZoomWindow(myImage, "test window")
    key = -1
    while key != ord('q') and key != 27: # 27 = escape key
        #the OpenCV window won't display until you call cv2.waitKey()
        key = cv2.waitKey(5) #User can press 'q' or ESC to exit.
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is deciding the scale changed every time on mouse wheel. After you get the current scale (v.s. origin image) and correct region of image you want to show on screen, you can get the position and length of rectangle on scaled image. So you can draw this rectangle on scaled image.

In my [github](https://github.com/DennisLiu1993/Fastest_Image_Pattern_Matching)，checking OnMouseWheel () and RefreshSrcView () in Fastest_Image_Pattern_Matching/ELCVMatchTool/ELCVMatchToolDlg.cpp may give what you want.

Although it's c++ code, but only imshow () and resize () are used. Focusing on how I change the scale and how the new rectangle to be draw in scaled image will be enough.

Besides, if you also want to zoom in/out by tracking scroll bars, also check the function "OnHScroll ()" for horizontal bar and "OnVScroll ()" for vertical bar.

Effect:
[image]
[image]

Part of the code:

```
BOOL CELCVMatchToolDlg::OnMouseWheel (UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt)
{
    POINT pointCursor;
    GetCursorPos (&pointCursor);
    ScreenToClient (&pointCursor);
    // TODO: 在此加入您的訊息處理常式程式碼和 (或) 呼叫預設值
    if (zDelta > 0)
    {
        if (m_iScaleTimes == MAX_SCALE_TIMES)
            return TRUE;
        else
            m_iScaleTimes++;
    }
    if (zDelta < 0)
    {
        if (m_iScaleTimes == MIN_SCALE_TIMES)
            return TRUE;
        else
            m_iScaleTimes--;
    }
    CRect rect;
    //GetWindowRect (rect);
    GetDlgItem (IDC_STATIC_SRC_VIEW)->GetWindowRect (rect);//重要

    if (m_iScaleTimes == 0)
        g_dCompensationX = g_dCompensationY = 0;

    int iMouseOffsetX = pt.x - (rect.left + 1);
    int iMouseOffsetY = pt.y - (rect.top + 1);

    double dPixelX = (m_hScrollBar.GetScrollPos () + iMouseOffsetX + g_dCompensationX) / m_dNewScale;
    double dPixelY = (m_vScrollBar.GetScrollPos () + iMouseOffsetY + g_dCompensationY) / m_dNewScale;


    m_dNewScale = m_dSrcScale * pow (SCALE_RATIO, m_iScaleTimes);

    if (m_iScaleTimes != 0)
    {
        int iWidth = m_matSrc.cols;
        int iHeight = m_matSrc.rows;

        
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollRange (0, int (m_dNewScale * iWidth - m_dSrcScale * iWidth) - 1 + BAR_SIZE);
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollRange (0, int (m_dNewScale * iHeight - m_dSrcScale * iHeight) - 1 + BAR_SIZE);
        int iBarPosX = int (dPixelX * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetX + 0.5);
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollPos (iBarPosX);
        m_hScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_SHOW);
        g_dCompensationX = -iBarPosX + (dPixelX * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetX);

        int iBarPosY = int (dPixelY * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetY + 0.5);
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollPos (iBarPosY);
        m_vScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_SHOW);
        g_dCompensationY = -iBarPosY + (dPixelY * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetY);

        //滑塊大小
        SCROLLINFO infoH;
        infoH.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
        infoH.fMask = SIF_PAGE;
        infoH.nPage = BAR_SIZE;
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollInfo (&infoH);

        SCROLLINFO infoV;
        infoV.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
        infoV.fMask = SIF_PAGE;
        infoV.nPage = BAR_SIZE;
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollInfo (&infoV);
        //滑塊大小

    }
    else
    {
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollPos (0);
        m_hScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_HIDE);
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollPos (0);
        m_vScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_HIDE);
    }
    RefreshSrcView ();
    return CDialogEx::OnMouseWheel (nFlags, zDelta, pt);
}
```